# @Value boolean returns 'invalid boolean value' of value true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm trying to simply get value from properties file, a boolean value of  `false` like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/conf/default/server.properties")
........
@Value("${startup.notify.enabled}")
private boolean enabled;
```

in properties file:

```
startup.notify.enabled=true
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${startup.notify.enabled}]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
```

Can this be because of placeholder `"${startup.notify.enabled}"`?

Comment: I just tried this myself, and this works fine as it is. You must be doing something different within your project that you haven't mentioned yet or you're using a different Spring boot version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@Value("#{new Boolean('${startup.notify.enabled}')}")
```

Works like a charm

EDIT

If you have trouble with other int, String, etc fields used with `@Value`, make sure you have `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in your Config file.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```